# Matrix Trace applied to Economics

Tags: matrices, dynamical-systems, trace

So... a friend of mine gave me the insight that the Matrix Trace in aerodynamics gives you the Total Kinetic energy of turbulence.
    Now, competitive dynamic systems can have dispersion and states that can resemble very complicated fluids in very high dimensions....
  Can we apply a matrix trace and interpret it to something like, say, Economics?

I worked on some Lotka-Volterra like systems, treating some parameters as a kind of "Heat" where the diffusion is variable and unique to each individual participant...

https://photos.app.goo.gl/eiL277a0JRrTQify1
   If i take the Trace, the TKE is basically, "the sum of everyone's Effort function".

https://photos.app.goo.gl/NohV8jHC05NahsIJ2

I've hit a wall a while back on this...    if anyone has insight on what Turbulence or Reynold's Flow could be a "metaphor" of in a High-Dimension Competitive system?

I know it sounds kind of arcane, but I really feel there's some insight i can gain on macro-economics, Long term trends of Memetics in society, etc.